# Algorithm To Calculate Different Types Of Memory

Tags: c#

I am trying to calculate memory. I have calculated Available, InUse, Free, and Cached with the following code

```
  ObjectQuery wql = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem");
            ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(wql);
            ManagementObjectCollection results = searcher.Get();

            //total amount of free physical memory in bytes
            var Available = new ComputerInfo().AvailablePhysicalMemory;
            //total amount of physical memory in bytes
            var Total = new ComputerInfo().TotalPhysicalMemory;

            var PhysicalMemoryInUse = Total - Available;
            Object Free = new object();
            foreach (var result in results)
            {
                //Free amount
                Free = result["FreePhysicalMemory"];
            } 
            var Cached = Total - PhysicalMemoryInUse - UInt64.Parse(Free.ToString());
```

How can I calculate Standby, Hardware Reserved, and Modified memory as shown in Resource Monitor in windows?

[image]

Comment: What is "standby memory" and "modified memory"?

Comment: @Scott the values you are showing from the resource monitor are the values I am looking for

Comment: Not sure if this works for you? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn958303(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Or look in the awesome process hacker to find the code you need. You may have to PInvoke it in C#. Follow this clue - look for "Hardware Reserved" in the thread https://wj32.org/processhacker/forums/viewtopic.php?t=2200

Comment: @MurrayFoxcroft Can you show me an example to use this in .net 3.5?

Comment: I looked at process hacker but its c++ code im not sure what to do?

Comment: If I get some time I'll translate it for you. For now, I'll post a dumper of all perf counters in an answer - see if what you need is in there first.

Comment: I also found this nugget, you could need to do a calc:  Note The amount of usable memory in the examples are not exact amounts. Usable memory is a calculated amount of the total physical memory minus "hardware reserved" memory.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hardware reserved is the difference between the amount of physically installed memory and the total amount of physical memory reported by the OS.

The other information can be retrieved by performance counters. I have an example class below, but know that this isn't a robust implementation. You'll want to add proper error handling and resource cleanup. However, caching an instance of this class and updating the values via `Refresh()` whenever you need it should perform fairly well.

```
public sealed class MemoryInfo : IDisposable
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool GetPhysicallyInstalledSystemMemory(out ulong memoryInKilobytes);

    private readonly PerformanceCounter availableCounter;
    private readonly PerformanceCounter modifiedCounter;
    private readonly PerformanceCounter freeCounter;
    private readonly PerformanceCounter standbyCoreCounter;
    private readonly PerformanceCounter standbyNormalCounter;
    private readonly PerformanceCounter standbyReserveCounter;

    private ulong osTotalMemory;

    public ulong ModifiedBytes { get; private set; }
    public ulong InUseBytes { get; private set; }
    public ulong StandbyBytes { get; private set; }
    public ulong FreeBytes { get; private set; }
    public ulong HardwareReserved { get; }

    public MemoryInfo()
    {
        var computerInfo = new ComputerInfo();

        osTotalMemory = computerInfo.TotalPhysicalMemory;

        ulong installedPhysicalMemInKb;
        GetPhysicallyInstalledSystemMemory(out installedPhysicalMemInKb);

        this.HardwareReserved = installedPhysicalMemInKb * 1024 - osTotalMemory;

        modifiedCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Memory", "Modified Page List Bytes");
        standbyCoreCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Memory", "Standby Cache Core Bytes");
        standbyNormalCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Memory", "Standby Cache Normal Priority Bytes");
        standbyReserveCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Memory", "Standby Cache Reserve Bytes");
        freeCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Memory", "Free & Zero Page List Bytes");
        availableCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Memory", "Available Bytes");

        Refresh();
    }

    public void Refresh()
    {
        ModifiedBytes = (ulong)modifiedCounter.NextSample().RawValue;
        StandbyBytes = (ulong)standbyCoreCounter.NextSample().RawValue +
                       (ulong)standbyNormalCounter.NextSample().RawValue +
                       (ulong)standbyReserveCounter.NextSample().RawValue;
        FreeBytes = (ulong)freeCounter.NextSample().RawValue;
        InUseBytes = osTotalMemory - (ulong) availableCounter.NextSample().RawValue;

    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        modifiedCounter.Dispose();
        standbyCoreCounter.Dispose();
        standbyNormalCounter.Dispose();
        standbyReserveCounter.Dispose();
        freeCounter.Dispose();
        availableCounter.Dispose();
    }
}
```

There are downsides to doing it this way, like the perf counters are not grouped together, so you don't get a 'real' snapshot of the system memory at a specific point in time. You can probably improve that using PInvoke to use the `Pdh*` win32 api functions directly.

You could also change it to use WMI (data is in `Win32_PerfRawData_PerfOS_Memory`) but I don't know how it would perform.

Answer (score 0):

See if what you are after is in here - create a console app and paste this over the content of program.cs. Run it from the command line and > to a file and look for the relevant memory counters.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var categories = PerformanceCounterCategory.GetCategories();

            foreach (var cat in categories)
            {
                if (cat.CategoryType != PerformanceCounterCategoryType.MultiInstance)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Category: " + cat.CategoryName);
                    foreach (var counter in cat.GetCounters())
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Counter: " + counter.CounterName + ": " + counter.NextSample().RawValue);
                    }
                }
                else //if (cat.CategoryType == PerformanceCounterCategoryType.MultiInstance)
                {
                    foreach (var instance in cat.GetInstanceNames())
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Instance: " + instance);
                        foreach (var counter in cat.GetCounters(instance))
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Counter: " + counter.CounterName + ": " + counter.NextSample().RawValue);
                            } catch
                            { 
                                // swallow exceptions for counter that require a set base. 
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            Console.ReadLine();           
        }      
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like Counter: Modified Page List Bytes: 62291968 and Counter: Standby Cache Normal Priority Bytes might be them but not sure? Would that make sense? Dont see hardware reserved

Comment: If these values are correct what is the fastest way to query to get to them? This code takes a longtime to run

Answer (score 0):

I used Christopher's sample and extended it to be all WMI to get Hardware Reserved.

```
using System;
using System.Management;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                ManagementScope Scope;
                Scope = new ManagementScope(String.Format("\\\\{0}\\root\\CIMV2", "."), null);
                Scope.Connect();

                double totalVisibleMemory = 0;

                ObjectQuery wql = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem");
                ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(wql);
                ManagementObjectCollection results = searcher.Get();

                foreach (ManagementObject result in results)
                {
                    totalVisibleMemory = double.Parse(result["TotalVisibleMemorySize"].ToString()) / 1024;
                    Console.WriteLine("Total Visible Memory: {0:0} mb", totalVisibleMemory);
                    Console.WriteLine("Free Physical Memory: {0:0} mb", double.Parse(result["FreePhysicalMemory"].ToString()) / 1024);
                    Console.WriteLine("Total Virtual Memory: {0:0} mb", double.Parse(result["TotalVirtualMemorySize"].ToString()) / 1024);
                    Console.WriteLine("Free Virtual Memory: {0:0} mb", double.Parse(result["FreeVirtualMemory"].ToString()) / 1024);
                }

                ObjectQuery Query = new ObjectQuery("SELECT Capacity FROM Win32_PhysicalMemory");
                ManagementObjectSearcher Searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(Scope, Query);
                UInt64 Capacity = 0;
                foreach (ManagementObject WmiObject in Searcher.Get())
                {
                    Capacity += (UInt64)WmiObject["Capacity"];
                }

                var totalPhysicalMemory = Capacity / (1024 * 1024); 
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Total Physical Memory {0:0} mb", Capacity / (1024 * 1024)));
                var hardwareReserved = totalPhysicalMemory - totalVisibleMemory;

                    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Hardware Reserved Memory {0:0} mb", hardwareReserved));
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Exception {0} Trace {1}", e.Message, e.StackTrace));
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to exit");
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```